# HTML Cannot Find Stylesheet in Different Directory

Tags: html, css, node.js

I am having trouble connecting my stylesheet in a different directory to my HTML files despite using the proper mechanism. Am I targeting the right level?

'-' indicates levels

Here is my file structure:

**myProject** (Parent)

-public (1st level)

--stylesheets (2nd level)

---styles.css (3rd level)

-Views (1st level)

--index.ejs (2nd  level)

HTML:

```
  <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Node Authentication</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles.css">


    </head>
```

Comment: you can't use relative path in html... it doesnt work that way.the browser has no knowledge of the document root, so  you will have to move it at or below your document root in order for the browser to find it.

Comment: can you post snapshot of treeview of the folder you mention above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you used the `Express Static` middleware this way in your app :

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Then in your view :

```
  <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Node Authentication</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/styles.css">


    </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that myProject is your html file, try

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public\stylesheets\styles.css" />
```

Comment: Your slashes are going the wrong way and the link element does not have a closing slash.

Comment: It works for me though....I've tested on Internet Explorer, Google Chrome and Firefox

Comment: Your slashes are still going the wrong way, though. There's a standard for that and what you are doing is wrong and proprietary to Windows operating systems only and not any network. For more evidence, see the address bar in any browser and any link on any web page but yours.